# How would I use php to generate random XML files?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to write a php that would generate random XML Files that I've previously written. As this php code generate random numbers between 10-30:

```
<?php
print rand() . "<br>";
//line 4 calls out a number between 10 and 30 inclusive
print rand(10,30);
?>
```

How would I be able to generate random XML Files?

I am a newbie at this, so apologies if this is a dumb question!

Any help will be seriously appreciated!

Sam

Comment: Do you need to pick from an existing set of XML files or do you want completely 100% random XML?

Comment: what's a "random xml file"? `<argle><bargle>wibble</bargle><aafasdfalsjdfasdfasdfasdfasdf /></argle>`?

Comment: RE Frits van Campen
A set of XML Files I've already created stored in different folder

Comment: RE: Marc B
As in whenever the page refreshes, a different XML file appears.

Comment: @user2245677: From a programming point of view it makes not much of difference if you genereate an XML string and save it to disk (into a file) or to stdout (a standard pipe, very similar to a file). In php if you use `php://stdout` as a filename it will be printed in the browser for example (the buffered one is `php://output` which behaves more like `echo` or `print`). Like [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829952/using-the-rand-php-function-to-display-random-xml-files#comment22520385_15829952) I also must admit that I do not see how the questions are different.

Answer (score 2):

you can store the xml files names in an array then use `array_rand()` to pick one randomly

Comment: Thanks, how would I store xml file names in an array?