# Using the rand () php function to display random xml files

Tags: php, xml, random

I am trying to write a php that generates xml files randomly. The php would generate a random number between 1-10 inclusive and each number 1-10 would have a xml file assigned to it in the php which would appear when the respective number is generated.

So far I have:

```
<?php
 print rand() . "<br>"; 
 print rand(1, 10); 
 ?>
```

How do I integrate the xml files into this php? Using this xml example:

**Example 1**

```
<?xml version="3.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<channel>
<title>The Dog in the Park</title> 
<link>http://pets.com/doginthepark/</link> 
<description>
  The dog in the park
<item> 
<guid>1234</guid>
<title>poodle's video</title>
```

**Example 2**

```
<?xml version="3.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<channel>
<title>The Cat in the Park</title> 
<link>http://pets.com/kitteninthepark/</link> 
<description>
  The cat in the park
<item> 
<guid>1235</guid>
<title>kitten video</title>
<item>
<guid>123455</guid>
<title>tiger video</title>
```

So the XML files above have the assigned numbers 1 & 2. How would I assign the number in code to the correct XML and how would I be able to generate a random XML return of the numbers 1-10 which also display the XML file details.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Sorry if this question is obvious, I'm a rookie at this :)

Comment: Are the xml-files named `1.xml`, `2.xml` ... and so on?

Comment: RE Marty McVry:
The XML Files would be called dogs.xml and cats.xml respectively.

Comment: RE Mark Baker:
The question you're referring to discusses generating XML files saved into a separate document rather than having them in the php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$XMLFiles = array ("path/dogs.xml", "path/cats.xml", "path/moreFiles.xml");
$XMLFile = $XMLFiles[rand(0,9)];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$XMLFile.'"');
print file_get_contents($XMLFile);
?>
```

Will directly output your one of your XML files as a XML file!
Dont output anything else when using headers!

Comment: Thanks! Would I paste the XML File details underneath?

Comment: What do you mean with file details? The filename? Or the contents?

Comment: The contents i.e what I pasted above

Comment: In this case, the routine should work as you expect, as long as you insert the right amount of paths into the $XMLFiles array. You can also use the glob function from @Dale to scan your directory for your xml files and fill your array with it. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

couldnt you just put the xml files into an array. then on submit of the page have something like this

```
   echo file_get_contents($xmlarray[rand(1,10)]);
```

I presume this would work. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way so that you don't have to recode the array random values every time you add a new xml file, and it wont matter what the files are called.

```
<?php

    $files = glob('path/to/files/*.xml');
    $xml = file_get_contents($files[rand(0, count($files)-1)]);
    // do something with the xml here
    echo $xml;

?>
```

For reference: [`glob`](http://php.net/glob), [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), [`rand`](http://php.net/rand), [`count`](http://php.net/count)

Comment: Thanks Dale, what do you mean by do something with xml here?
Sorry if that's a dumb question

Comment: Well I don't know what you want to do with it.. you could mail it to someone or just output to the browser for example, in the answer I've given it is output to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's exactly what I want to do.